# search string inside key and values of a associative array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array looks like this one blow =>

```
$aarray = [
  "table" => "Balance",
  "where" => ["Balance[+]" => "NOMONEY[-]"]
     ];
```

how i can search through that for words like "[+]" or "[-]" and replace them with something else ?
**ps : wanna search and replace in both key and value of associative array**
**another ps : I cant find anything doing same as i wish in google or this forum**

Comment: Simply do a recursion on array.

Comment: @MarkusZeller can u pls give me a example ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and replace string with condition in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216852/find-and-replace-string-with-condition-in-php)

Comment: @AhmetFiratKeler no . this used for string not associative (nested)) array . i wanna search and replace in both key and value at same time or together somehow .

Comment: Can we have a bigger [mcve] which covers all possible scenarios? Will the `where` subarray be the only place these occur? Is recursion necessary or do your arrays have a known maximum depth?

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68190329/2943403   You'll notice that replacing the string values is child's play after setting up the recursive key replacement functionality.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3560300/2943403) can be easily modified to suit your needs like [this](https://3v4l.org/kpk4R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sample data, you could nest as deep as you want until PHP's recursion limit.

```
$array = [
    "table" => "Balance",
    "where" => ["Balance[+]" => "NOMONEY[-]"],
];

$new = replaceInArray($array, "[-]", "(minus)");
$new = replaceInArray($new, "[+]", "(plus)");
print_r($new);
```

Here is a simple recursive function to replace keys and values

```
function replaceInArray($array, $search, $replace, &$newArray = [])
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $key = str_replace($search, $replace, $key);
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $newArray[$key] = replaceInArray($value, $search, $replace);
        } else {
            $newArray[$key] = str_replace($search, $replace, $value);
        }
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

will print out

```
Array
(
    [table] => Balance
    [where] => Array
        (
            [Balance(plus)] => NOMONEY(minus)
        )

)
```

Comment: Food for thought... a single parameter in the function signature: https://3v4l.org/kpk4R

Comment: @mickmackusa I thought about an replacement array as parameter, but I thought this is easer to read for a simple answer. Nice idea to do it that way you suggested, I would have chosen a class with const or property to make it have less parameters.